# Disable JAVA SSL3

Tags: java, ssl

as there's the new Poodle Bug in SSL3 we'd like to disable SSL3 on all of our servers and use only tls. As some of our software is using the Java implementation and doesn't offer any configuration for not accepting SSL3 we're a searching for a possibility to make our servers save again.

Until now we tried to disable "OLD SSL" and just use starttls, but starttls (startssl) still allows to use SSL3 :/

I hope you can help me,
cheers
Chris
(As this is my first time asking here I'm not sure if I did everything right, but I hope so)

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to ask the same question with focus on cli/command.

If you are in a Windows environment you can click:

Start -> Java -> Configure Java

In the open "Java Control Panel" go to "Advanced" tab and scroll down.

There you can unmark the "Use SSL 3.0" box.

I'd be interested in a command that does the same for roll-out on multiple servers, so Question needn't be answered with my post.   ;-)

Comment: well, we're trying to fix it on linux servers, so there's nothing like an UI, but thanks for that hint.